# how to put code

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, code-block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

hey!! how do i put my code in this question window... am new to this i donno, pls help...

Comment: And migrated as well.  An excellent addition.

Answer (score 0):

Indent your code with four spaces by clicking the `{ }` button on the editor toolbar.